# Put key on wrong record

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a problem connecting app maker with Google Cloud Platform. First I created two tables with one(department) to many(employee) relation. I also created an employee form.

Datasource on panel using employee, and on form using `inherited:employee(create)`. Submit button using `SaveChanges To Datasource`. My Problem is, when I create the first record, it only saves employee data, while `department_fk` is empty.

When I create the second record, it will create data, but the `department_fk` will be placed on the first record.

```
+------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|  id  |  name  | department_fk |         email         |   phone   |
+------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| 150  | john   | 262           | bermuara@gmail.com    | 3393939   |
| 151  | brian  | NULL          | takdungder@gmail.com  | 03030303  |
+------+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

On the above record, brian should be in `department_fk 262`, but it assigns it on john's record. How do I fix it?

Comment: You either need to have a field in the employee form that assigns the department or you need to have client or server script that assigns the department to the employee. This value would not get assigned all by itself, so there seems to be something missing in your question, specifically how are you assigning your department to the employee?

Comment: I solved this problem by change datasource. On Panel I change it to department, and on form I use Employee (create). it write key  on the same record.